# pygame how to make a parent sprite group that contains another group

Tags: python, pygame

so I have an all_sprites group in pygame that contains all my sprites. to do this I simply make them be in that group on initiation. Also there are mobs and they are inside the mobs group along with the all_sprite group. I make them update along with all the other sprites I have with an update() function:

```
self.all_sprites.update()
```

simple stuff. But I want to update only the mobs in the area aound the player, so I could simply

```
self.all_sprite.add(Mob)
self.all_sprite.remove(Mob)
```

if they are or arent in the zone, its simple but the remove function is wayyy slower than the empty one, in fact I use

```
self.walls.empty()
```

before every loop and just add the walls inside the screen after and it works like a charm. But the walls dont have an update function so here comes my problem, I want that if I empty my mobs group, it removes the mobs in the all_sprite group aswell, like a parent group, and if I add a mob in the mobs group, it adds one to the all_sprites. all of this without using the remove() function in pygame because it is slow. is there a way I can do this?

sorry for not providing the full code, its kinda huge (~50 kB of text) but I believe my exemples are enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the mobs from the sprite groups if they are not in the zone and rather add a conditional statement to their `update` method to make sure they're only updated if the distance to the player is below the desired threshold, e.g.:

```
def update(self):
    if distance_to_player < 150:
        # Rest of the update code ...
```

You probably need to store a reference to the player in the mob instances to calculate the distance.

Comment: yes I already have a condition for their update, sadly just calling their update even if it does nothing, when there is alot (few thousands) it makes me lose a bit of fps, I wanted to find a way to bypass completly the update calling for the mob group if they arent on screen, thanks for the answer tho!

Comment: Okay, that's important information which should be in the question not in a comment. There's no trivial solution for your optimization problem and I'm not sure if you can achieve a good performance with so many sprites in pygame and Python. [Spatial partitioning](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html) will probably be helpful to you. I think someone has already written a quadtree module for pygame. Perhaps you have to switch the game library/engine as well and use Cython for critical parts of the code if nothing helps (use profilers to find the hot spots in your program).

Comment: I'll look into Cython, I already do spartial partitionning, my programs even when the map is 8192x8192 stays at 60 fps even if 20ish mobs runs after you (getting uptated) but it goes to 40-45 fps when there are thousands of mobs on the map (not updating nor getting blit) and that 20ish mobs runs after you, I already use cProfile and its what showed me that the update function getting called almost half  a million time every 10sec even if the update does nothing is what makes me lag :/